# What formats can matplotlib animations be saved as?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, codec

I've been learning matplotlib's animation package, and all of the examples seem to save the file as `.mp4`. The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) doesn't mention any other specific formats. Are there other file formats that matplotlib can use to save the animation? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That depends on the `writer` argument of the [`.save()` method](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.Animation.save):

> **writer** is either an instance of MovieWriter or a string key that
>   identifies a class to use, such as ‘ffmpeg’ or ‘mencoder’. If nothing
>   is passed, the value of the rcparam animation.writer is used.

Matplotlib uses an external process(that you need to have installed) to join the frames. If you are using for example `'ffmpeg'` you can find the supported format/codecs with:

```
ffmpeg -formats
ffmpeg -codecs
```

In the listing you will see that some codecs are marked with an **E** meaning encoding is supported in this format.